# what's the proper way to allow users to provide a string "mangler" as a regex/proc/expr/

Tags: string, tcl, user-input

In my Tcl/Tk project, i need to allow my users to mangle a string in a well-defined way.

The idea is, to allow people to declare a "string mangling" proc/expr/function/... in a configuration file, which then gets applied to the strings in question.

I'm a bit worried on how to properly implement that.

Possibilities I have considered so far:

- regular expressions

  That was my first thought, but there's two caveats:

  - search/replace with regular expressions in Tcl seems to be awkward. at least with [regsub](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/regsub.htm) i need to pass the match and replacement parts separately (as opposed to how e.g. `sed` allows me to pass a single complicated string that does everything for me); there are [`sed` implementations](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/sed) for Tcl, but they look naive and might break rather sooner than later
  - also regexes can be awkward by themselves; using them to mangle complicated strings is often more complicated than it should be
- procs?

  Since the target platform is Tcl anyhow, why not use the power of Tcl to do string mangling?
  The "function" should have a single input and produce a single output, and ideally it the user should be nudged into doing it right (e.g. not being able to define a proc that requires two arguments) and it be (nigh) impossible to create side-effects (like changing the state of the application).

  A simplistic approach would be to use `proc mymangler s $body` (with `$body` being the string defined by the user), but there are so many things that can go wrong:

  - `$body` assuming a different arg-name (e.g. `$x` instead of `$s`)
  - `$body` not returning anything
  - `$body` changing variables,... in the environment

  `expr`essions look more like it (always returning things, not allowing to modify the environment easily), but i cannot make them work on strings, and there's no way to pass a variable without agreeing its name.

So, the best I've come up with so far is:

```
set userfun {return $s}      # user-defined string
proc mymangler s ${userfun}
set output [mymangler $input]
```

Are there better ways to achieve user-defined string-manglers in Tcl?

Comment: The tcl wiki has [a lot of stuff on configuration files](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/Techniques+for+reading+and+writing+application+configuration+files) that is useful reading, btw.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`apply`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/apply.htm) -- the user provides a 2-element list: the second element is the "proc body", the code that does the mangling; the first element is the variable name to hold the string, this variable is used in the body.

For example:

```
set userfun {{str} {string reverse $str}}
set input "some string"
set result [apply $userfun $input]    ;# => "gnirts emos"
```

Of course the code you get from the user is any arbitrary Tcl code. You can run it in a [safe interpreter](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/safe.htm):

```
set userfun {{str} {exec some malicious code; return [string reverse $str]}}

try {
    set interp [safe::interpCreate]
    set result [$interp eval [list apply $userfun $input]]
    puts "mangled string is: $result"
    safe::interpDelete $interp
} on error e {
    error "Error: $e"
}
```

results in

```
Error: invalid command name "exec"
```

Notes:

- a standard Tcl command is used, `apply`
- the user must specify the variable name used in the body.
- this scheme does protect the environment:

  ```
  set userfun {{str} {set ::env(SOME_VAR) "safe slave"; return $str$str}}
  set env(SOME_VAR) "main"

  puts $env(SOME_VAR)
  try {
      set interp [safe::interpCreate]
      set result [$interp eval [list apply $userfun $input]]
      puts "mangled string is: $result"
      safe::interpDelete $interp
  } on error e {
      error "Error: $e"
  }
  puts $env(SOME_VAR)
  ```

  outputs

  ```
  main
  mangled string is: some stringsome string
  main
  ```
- if the user does not return a value, then the mangled string is simply the empty string.

Answer (score 1):

The "simplistic" approach is like `foreach` in that it requires the user to supply a variable name and a script to evaluate that uses that variable, and is a good approach. If you don't want it affecting the rest of the program, run it in a separate interpreter:

```
set x 0
proc mymangler {name body} {
   set i [interp create -safe]
   set s "some string to change"
   try {
       # Build the lambda used by apply here instead of making
       # the user do it.
       $i eval [list apply [list $name $body] $s]
   } on error e {
       return $e
   } finally {
      interp delete $i
   }
}
puts [mymangler s { set x 1; string toupper $s }]
puts $x
```

outputs

```
SOME STRING TO CHANGE
0
```

If the person calling this says to use `s` as a variable and then uses something else in the body, it's on them. Same with providing a script that doesn't return anything.

Comment: Since you want this in a configuration file, your actual `mymangler` code would probably just save the varname and script somewhere and then you'd actually call it at a more appropriate spot, of course.

Answer (score 1):

I'd generally allow the user to specify a *command prefix* as a Tcl list (most simple command names are trivially suitable for this), which you would then apply to the argument by doing:

```
set mangled [{*}$commandPrefix $valueToMangle]
```

This lets people provide pretty much anything they want, especially as they can use `apply` and a lambda term to mangle things as required. Of course, if you're in a procedure then you're probably actually better off doing:

```
set mangled [uplevel 1 [list {*}$commandPrefix $valueToMangle]]
```

so that you're running in the caller's context (change `1` to `#0` to use the global context instead) which can help protect your procedure against accidental changes and make using `upvar` within the mangler easier.

If the source of the mangling prefix is untrusted (what that means depends greatly on your application and deployment) then you can run the mangling code in a separate interpreter:

```
# Make the safe evaluation context; this is *expensive*
set context [interp create -safe]
# You might want to let them define extra procedures too
#     interp invokehidden $context source /the/users/file.tcl

# Use the context
try {
    set mangled [interp eval $context [list {*}$commandPrefix $valueToMangle]]
} on error {msg} {
    # User supplied something bad; error message in $msg
}
```

There's various ways to support users specifying the transformation, but if you can expose the fact that you're working with Tcl to them then that's probably easiest and most flexible.